# How to pass variables between HTML pages using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new to using Flask and I've just been trying to pass a variable between two web pages. The first is a simple form to accept a number with the second page just displaying what is entered.

HTML for the form page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action ="{{ url_for('return_form', glon="glon") }}" method="post">
            Galactic Longitude: <input type="text" name="glon">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML for the display page:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>

<p> {{ glon }} </p>

</body>
</html>
```

The Flask script currently looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/form/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        glon = request.form['glon']
        #glat = request.form['glat']

        return redirect(url_for('return_form', glon=glon))

    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/return_form/<glon>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def return_form(glon):
    return render_template('return_form.html', glon=glon)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

At the moment, the second page just displays "glon" instead of the number passed to the form.

I simply want the variable to display on the second page, and eventually use it in the return_form function.

Comment: Use HTTP method GET or POST

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So i didn't got your approach.Below is what i did,I changed the code a bit. Hope this solves your problem.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/form', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        glon = request.form['glon']
        return render_template('display.html', glon=glon)

# @app.route('/return_form/<glon>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
# def return_form(glon):
#     return render_template('return_form.html', glon=glon)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action ="{{ url_for('form') }}" method="post">
            Galactic Longitude: <input type="text" name="glon">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

display.html

```
<!doctype html>
<body>

<p> {{ glon }} </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried this method and couldn't get it work either, I'm not sure how the form.html template is rendered in this example as well.